# How do you convert SYS_GUID() to varchar?

Tags: oracle, guid

In oracle 10g, how do you convert SYS_GUID() to varchar?  I am trying something like:

```
select USER_GUID from user where email = 'user@example.com'
```

Which returns the RAW byte[].  Is it possible to use a function to convert the RAW to VARCHAR2 in the SQL statement?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't forget to use `HEXTORAW(varchar2)` when comparing this value to the `RAW` columns.

There is no implicit convesion from `VARCHAR2` to `RAW`. That means that this clause:

```
WHERE raw_column = :varchar_value
```

will be impicitly converted into:

```
WHERE RAWTOHEX(raw_column) = :varchar_value
```

, thus making indices on `raw_column` unusable.

Use:

```
WHERE raw_column = HEXTORAW(:varchar_value)
```

instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use RAWTOHEX(USER_GUID).

Answer (score 4):

```
select RAWTOHEX(USER_GUID) from user where email = 'user@example.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't mod-1 if I'm wrong. I'm going from memory so this a disclaimer to verify.

TO_CHAR is actually different between SQL and PL/SQL.

In SQL TO_CHAR does not take a raw as you have found out.

In PL/SQL To_CHAR will take a raw value.

So if you're in a procedure anyways, sometimes it easier to use a variable, but if you're just using SQL, go with the other answers here.

Comment: PL/SQL's TO_CHAR() is in fact SYS.STANDARD.TO_CHAR(), which you can use in SQL too: SELECT SYS.STANDARD.TO_CHAR(SYS_GUID()) FROM dual. Of course this implies SQL/PLSQL context switch and appropriate performance impact.

Comment: OMG, that's so cool. I never contextualized it like that. mod+1.1

Answer (score 1):

`select CAST (USER_GUID AS VARCHAR2(100))   from user where email = 'user@example.com'`